# I'm going to make a time display using javascript with the following conditions, how can I do this?

Tags: javascript, date

how do i make a time display using javascript with the following conditions below:

1. If the message is received today, only the "hour" will appear.
2. If the message is received yesterday, it will only appear **yesterday and the hour**.
3. If the message is received this week, it will only display **the day and time**.
4. If the message is received in this year, it will only appear **date and month only** without years.
5. if the message is received last year or previous year, it will appear **date-month-year**.

example :

> 1. 08:00
> 2. Yesterday 08:00
> 3. Monday 08:00
> 4. 23 Jul
> 5. 23 Jul 2016

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please attempt something, then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, I would highly recommend using Moment.js.

```js
console.log(moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()); // 7 years ago
console.log(moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()); // 6 years ago
console.log(moment().startOf('day').fromNow());        // 8 minutes ago
console.log(moment().endOf('day').fromNow());          // in a day
console.log(moment().startOf('hour').fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can find more information [here](https://momentjs.com#relative-time).

Comment: How about use pure javascript ? how can I do like that ?

Comment: You really shouldn't answer questions that are asked so poorly. There are many libraries and many similar answers already that do relative, time-ago or "friendly" dates.

Comment: @RobG There is nothing wrong with the way this question was asked, and if I have enough information to understand the question and come up with a viable solution, I’m going to answer it. I suggest you do the same.